# saveInstanceState is always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I currently have a fragment attached to the activity. When I rotate my device, expect the details and position of grid to be saved and restored when the view is created again. The `onSavedStateInstance()` runs fine and I bundle up everything, but when the `onCreateView()` of the fragment is invoked, the stateInstance is `null`. I know a similar question has been asked and answered before but it did not really help in my case. Here are some snippets that may be useful to debug.

MainActivityFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        gridViewObjects = (List<GridViewObject>) savedInstanceState.get(movieKey);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
    } else {
        gridViewObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(movieKey, (ArrayList) gridViewObjects);
    outState.putInt("position", gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="app.sunshine.android.example.com.popmovies.MainActivityFragment">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo_500)));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Edit: On debug, I see that on device orientation change, the activity is re-created and the savedInstanceState in `OnCreate()` method is not null. The bundle details are intact. It's only when the fragment is created, the savedInstanceState in `OnCreateView()` is null.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in code where you're trying to put any key value pair inside `savedInstanceState`. call `onConfigurationChanged()` to get the value from bundle

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the post.

Comment: You're saving the value of `gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`, but you're restoring it to a field called `position`.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Yes, what I'm doing with the position is this: `gridView.setSelection(position);`

Comment: Can you post R.layout.activity_main as well? If the fragment does not have an ID or a tag, there's nothing to save.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    

         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            gridViewObjects = (List<GridViewObject>) savedInstanceState.get(movieKey);
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        } else {
            gridViewObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

And

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not help. Here's what's happening. On orientation change, the activity is created again. So on mainActivity (not the fragment)  the instance is not null and I can view the details of the bundle. But when the fragment view is created (onCreateView), the savedInstanceState is null.